# Power / Root function issue

Tags: arithmetic

I'm having trouble finding the answer for this, or really any Nth root problem.  Here is the particular problem that I cannot figure out.  A simple explanation of how to solve this would go a long way, thank you.

> Evaluate the function $\sqrt[5]{-243}$.

Comment: You are looking for the number $a$ with the property that $a^5 = -243$. Can you think of a number whose fifth power is $243$?

Comment: Oh my god that's it?  Thank you!  Edit: 3

Comment: Except $3$ doesn't work, because $3^5 = 243$ and you want the answer to be $-243$; so you'll need to do something to that $3$ to make sure you get $-243$ instead...

Comment: -3 =)  Thank you Arturo

Comment: For what it's worth, $\root5\of{-243}$ is not a function; it's a number. One key to success in Mathematics is understanding the vocabulary, and using it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

> You are looking for the number $a$ with the property that $a^5=−243$. Can
> you think of a number whose fifth power is 243? – Arturo Magidin Mar
> 26 at 3:43
>
> Oh my god that's it? Thank you! Edit: 3 – stytown Mar 26 at 3:45
>
> Except $3$ doesn't work, because $3^5=243$ and you want the
> answer to be $−243$; so you'll need to do something to that $3$ to make
> sure you get $−243$ instead... – Arturo Magidin Mar 26 at 3:46
>
> -3 =) Thank you Arturo – stytown Mar 26 at 3:51

Comment: Copy/pasting the relevant comments into a CW answer so that this question can be considered "answered" (when this answer is accepted or upvoted).  Feel free to edit/improve.